# Docker root dir cannot be found for nodes in Docker for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm, diskspace, docker-aws

I used [Docker for AWS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/) to create a Docker swarm cluster. In every node of this cluster, I found Docker root dir is `/var/lib/docker`, however, I cannot find this directory in file system.

`docker info` shows this:

```
~ $ docker info
Containers: 7
 Running: 7
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 9
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: awslogs
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: k8nw4j8bt0mhip541vurvd785
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 10.x.y.z
 Manager Addresses:
  10.x.y.z:2377
  10.x.y.z:2377
  10.x.y.z:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.36-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.293GiB
Name: ip-10-x-y-z.us-west-2.compute.internal
ID: 4YZB:UYHX:REW2:ENBZ:AAEW:BS6T:HB5B:OQCE:FRBU:DPXX:SJWV:GRGL
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 163
 Goroutines: 233
 System Time: 2018-06-13T07:04:01.824290758Z
 EventsListeners: 5
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 os=linux
 region=us-west-2
 availability_zone=us-west-2a
 instance_type=m3.large
 node_type=worker
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

It clearly shows the `Docker Root Dir` is `/var/lib/docker`, however, when I use `ls`, it says the directory cannot be found:

```
~ $ sudo ls /var/lib/docker
ls: /var/lib/docker: No such file or directory

~ $ sudo ls -al /var/lib/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Jun 25  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 27  2017 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun 25  2017 apk
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun 25  2017 misc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun 25  2017 udhcpd
```

About Docker's disk usage, there are over 2.3GB disk used by Docker

```
/ $ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              9                   6                   2.361GB             1.702GB (72%)
Containers          7                   7                   665.1kB             0B (0%)
Local Volumes       6                   6                   19.85MB             0B (0%)
```

About file system usage, `df` command shows 2.9GB space is used, which is expected since Docker alone consumes over 2.3GB.

```
/ $ sudo df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  19.7G      2.9G     15.8G  15% /
tmpfs                     3.6G         0      3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     3.6G         0      3.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                     3.6G    161.2M      3.5G   4% /etc/group
tmpfs                     3.6G    161.2M      3.5G   4% /etc/passwd
tmpfs                     3.6G    161.2M      3.5G   4% /etc/shadow
/dev/xvdb1               19.7G      2.9G     15.8G  15% /etc/ssh
tmpfs                     3.6G    161.2M      3.5G   4% /home/docker
/dev/xvdb1               19.7G      2.9G     15.8G  15% /var/log
/dev/xvdb1               19.7G      2.9G     15.8G  15% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/xvdb1               19.7G      2.9G     15.8G  15% /etc/hostname
/dev/xvdb1               19.7G      2.9G     15.8G  15% /etc/hosts
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   746.8M    916.0K    745.9M   0% /var/run/docker.sock
tmpfs                     3.6G    161.2M      3.5G   4% /usr/bin/docker
tmpfs                     3.6G         0      3.6G   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                     3.6G         0      3.6G   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                     3.6G         0      3.6G   0% /proc/sched_debug
tmpfs                     3.6G         0      3.6G   0% /sys/firmware
```

At the same time, about disk usage:

```
/ $ sudo du -h -d 1
0   ./sys
31.5M   ./usr
1.8M    ./etc
0   ./proc
12.0K   ./home
216.0K  ./sbin
4.0K    ./tmp
8.0K    ./run
4.0K    ./root
1.4M    ./bin
114.3M  ./var
4.0K    ./mnt
16.0K   ./media
2.8M    ./lib
0   ./dev
4.0K    ./srv
152.2M  .
```

`du` reports only 152.2M disk is used, and `/var` folder has only 114.3M used, and it seems `du` fails to find the /var/lib/docker as well, and Docker stores its data (2.3+GB) in some way `du` cannot find.

If I used `docker inspect` to inspect one of the running container on this node, it shows multiple folders are under `/var/lib/docker`.

Can anyone shed some light on the cause? Thanks.

Comment: Could you exec ls -al  /var/lib/ ?

Comment: @IgnacioMillán I updated the question with the output, it has three sub directories `apk`, `misc` and `udhcpd` under `/var/lib`, but there is no `docker` sub directory.

Comment: @nybon did you figure this out? I can't find docker root dir either. I suspect it's because docker for aws uses a shell container (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/faqs/#what-are-the-editions-containers-running-after-deployment) when you SSH into an instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because docker for aws uses a shell container when you ssh with the docker user (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/faqs/#what-are-the-editions-containers-running-after-deployment), so you don't actually have access to the host where the root dir is.

You can get access to the host through a privileged container, by first sshing with the docker user, then running something like: `docker run --rm -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh`